# Declarate only several columns from table

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

get some trouble with declaring JPA models. I have table with big count of columns and a lot of them are foreign keys to another tables. I need only several of them for my service. IS there any way to declare only several fields for correct work of JPA instead of declaring 50+ useless fields?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply don't declare the fields for those columns in the entity class.

However, unmapped columns must obviously be nullable if you intend to persist new entities that are mapped that way.